# How to clone a dictionary (and its content)?

Tags: actionscript-3, dictionary, clone

I googled some time to find a way to clone a dic, and I found some options, but they didnt work. One was to use a byteArray, it works only if you register all the clases involved and your classes have all their constructor parameters with default values <- not a choice in my case.

Ohter was, a copy but only for the first values, this one:

```
private function clone(original:Dictionary):Dictionary {
    var cloned:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
    for(var key:Object in original) {
        cloned[key] = original[key];
    }
    return cloned;
}
```

But, it doesnt clone a dicionary inside the main dictionary.

Do you know how to make a perfect clone of a given dictionary, even if it has another dictionary inside?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make a recursive function that checks the elements type, if they are dictionaries themselves keep recursing and copying.

Something like (untested):

```
private function clone(original:Dictionary):Dictionary {
    var cloned:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
    for(var key:Object in original) {
      if( original[key]  is Dictionary)
         cloned[key] = clone(original[key]);
      else
         cloned[key] = original[key];
    }
    return cloned;
}
```

Edit :

Seems to work for a simple nested dictionary like this :

```
var dic:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
dic["test"] = 5;
dic["otherDic"] = new Dictionary();
dic["otherDic"]["foo"] = 1;
dic["otherDic"]["bar"] = "bar";

var copy:Dictionary = clone(dic);

dic["test"] = 0;
dic["otherDic"]["foo"] = 0;
dic["otherDic"]["bar"] = "changed";
    //copy doesn't change, copy and dic are different dictionaries
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it doesn't throw any error but they are still the same object.

Comment: @sch you are correct if the dictionary is holding objects other than  simple types they will need to be properly copied. This works for simple types.

Comment: I create arrays of custom objects, and then I put them inside the dictionaries, when I loop throught the dics, and I do a removeChild, they get removed, but, if I create the objects manually, it works. What I understand from that, is that the objects are the same, they are not a copy, they are the same object.

Comment: @Artemix you can replace the line cloned[key] = original[key]; with a cloning function, or have the classes have a clone function which return an new instance of themselves that copy their properties.

Comment: @Baris the thing is, that the content of the dictionary (not the dictionaries inside) are primitive types, if instead of ints or strings, you use, for example, a Sprite, it wont work.

Comment: @Artemix if you are storing only Sprites then you can easily make a function that copies sprites and use that instead of cloned[key] = original[key]. Like cloned[key] = cloneSprite(original[key]);. If you have bunch of different types than I would extend them from a common base class and let them each have a clone function that can be called like: cloned[key] = original[key].clone(); The clone function will simply create a new instance and copy the properties of the sprite or whatever object it is.